# How to build a json file in jenkins inside a for loop

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to build a json file in a jenkins job.

I have a list of repos with a list of branches for each repo. I want to take this data and build a json file with it.

the end result should look like

```
[
    {
    "name": "repoName", 
    "branches" : 
        [
        "name" : "branchName",
        "name" : "branchName2"
        ]
    },
    {
    "name": "repoName2", 
    "branches" : 
        [
        "name" : "branchName",
        "name" : "branchName2",
        "name" : "branchName3",
        ]
    }
]
```

repoName and branchName both come from vars.

my code looks like this

```
script {
    node{
        unstash 'build'
        env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
        def buildConfig = load "GenerateBuildSelections.Groovy"
        def repos = buildConfig.GetListOfRepos("${env.WORKSPACE}/Repos.json")

        for(i = 0; i < repos.size(); i++){
            def repoName = repos[i]
            httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', authentication: '********-****-****-****-************', consoleLogResponseBody: true, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', outputFile: "branches_${repoName}.json", responseHandle: 'NONE', url: "https://api.github.com/repos/GenesisGaming/${repoName}/branches"
            env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
            def branches = buildConfig.GetListOfBranches("${env.WORKSPACE}/branches_${repoName}.json")

            //How do I save the Repo name with the branches here without overwriting the builder everytime
         }
     }
 }
```

I want to be able to save each repo with the list of branches all to the same json. I cant figure out how to do this without overwriting it every time.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by "without overwriting the builder". can you include the code that you tried and the resulting wrong file? is the problem that the file includes just one repo? if so, i think you need to initialize a HashMap, populate it as you iterate, and then dump it to json at the end.

Comment: Thanks that helped I was able to get it working with the hashmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

burnettk pointed me towards using a hashmap which worked perfectly. Here is the updated code that saves it to a json.

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage ('Create Build Parameters'){
        steps{
            sh 'echo !---SETUP---!'
            git credentialsId: '', url: 'https://github.com/GenesisGaming/DevOpsJenkins.git'
            httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', authentication: '', consoleLogResponseBody: false, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', outputFile: 'Repos.json', responseHandle: 'NONE', url: 'https://api.github.com/search/code?q=org:GenesisGaming+filename:Project.xml&per_page=100'
            readFile 'Repos.json'
            stash includes: '**', name: 'build'
            script {
                node{
                    unstash 'build'
                    env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
                    def buildConfig = load "GenerateBuildSelections.Groovy"
                    def repos = buildConfig.GetListOfRepos("${env.WORKSPACE}/Repos.json")

                    def dataMap = new HashMap<String,List>()
                    for(i = 0; i < repos.size(); i++){
                        def repoName = repos[i]
                        httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', authentication: '', consoleLogResponseBody: false, contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', outputFile: "branches_${repoName}.json", responseHandle: 'NONE', url: "https://api.github.com/repos/GenesisGaming/${repoName}/branches"
                        env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
                        def branches = buildConfig.GetListOfBranches("${env.WORKSPACE}/branches_${repoName}.json")
                        dataMap.put("${repoName}", "${branches}")

                    }
                    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(dataMap)
                    new File("/home/service/BuildSelectionOptions/options.json").write(builder.toPrettyString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
post {
    always {
        sh 'echo !---Cleanup---!'
        cleanWs()
    }
}
}
```